# inserting dbt execution message in snowfake log table

Tags: dbt

I am excuting my models on daily basis and wants to keep log of its execution in a snowflake model for report purpose.
I used **result** object to read information of executions like name ,status,rows_affected,execution_time. Along with this I want to save "Message" from result in my table.
I am currently taking result object as dictionary and while fetching message, I use below:
{% set node1 = tojson(run_result_dict.get('message',{})) %}
but when there is an error like
**Database Error in model dim_customerfile (models\customer.sql)
000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 126 at position 2
invalid identifier 'CC.name1'**
I am unable to insert it in my table using simple insert statement.

I tried using replace

```
  insert into  execution_log(err_message) 
values(
 replace(replace("Database Error in model dim_customerfile (models\customer.sql)
  000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 126 at position 2
  invalid identifier 'CC.name1'",'\'', ''''),'\'')
 )
```

but its giving error for

Error: invalid identifier '"Database Error in model dim_customerfile (models\customer.sql)